# Reshaping data.frame in R from wide to long format

Tags: r

I have data something like this.

| new_death | beds_covid | beds_noncrit | beds_icu_covid | icu_covid | vent_covid | hosp_covid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 434 | 1408 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 18 |
| 1 | 143 | 1183 | 16 | 2 | 1 | 46 |
| 2 | 280 | 1424 | 20 | 1 | 1 | 78 |

I want to change the table into something like this.

| new_death | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | beds_covid | 434 |
| 0 | beds_noncrit | 1408 |
| 0 | beds_icu_covid | 10 |
| 0 | icu_covid | 0 |
| 0 | vent_covid | 0 |
| 0 | hosp_covid | 18 |
| 1 | beds_covid | 143 |
| 1 | beds_noncrit | 1183 |
| 1 | beds_icu_covid | 16 |
| 1 | icu_covid | 2 |
| 1 | vent_covid | 1 |
| 1 | hosp_covid | 46 |

Thank you.

Comment: This is a very frequently asked R question. I like `tidyr::pivot_longer(df1, new_death)` but you'll see there are a variety of approaches you can use in R. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format for a good survey of these.

Answer (score -1):

use `reshape2::melt` function

```
df %>%
  melt(id.vars = 'new_death')

#>       new_death       variable value
#>    1          0     beds_covid   434
#>    2          1     beds_covid   143
#>    3          2     beds_covid   280
#>    4          0   beds_noncrit  1408
#>    5          1   beds_noncrit  1183
#>    6          2   beds_noncrit  1424
#>    7          0 beds_icu_covid    10
#>    8          1 beds_icu_covid    16
#>    9          2 beds_icu_covid    20
#>    10         0      icu_covid     0
#>    11         1      icu_covid     2
#>    12         2      icu_covid     1
#>    13         0     vent_covid     0
#>    14         1     vent_covid     1
#>    15         2     vent_covid     1
#>    16         0     hosp_covid    18
#>    17         1     hosp_covid    46
#>    18         2     hosp_covid    78
```